# pdftron copy wrong text

Tags: javascript, laravel, pdftron

I want to use [pdftron](https://www.pdftron.com/) and all things work perfect but when i copy text from pdf some characters convert to blank square and question mark, any idea?

[here](https://docdro.id/6NiA5kv) is my pdf.

As you can see below:
[image]

I wrote this code:

```
WebViewer({
    path: '/assets/plugins/pdftron',
    initialDoc: '/practical.pdf',
    fullAPI: true,
    disableLogs: true
}, document.getElementById('pdf')).then((instance) => {
    // PDFNet is only available with full API enabled
    const { PDFNet, docViewer } = instance;

    let Feature = instance.Feature;
    instance.disableFeatures([Feature.NotesPanel]);

    docViewer.on('documentLoaded', () => {
        // call methods relating to the loaded document
    });


    instance.textPopup.add({
        type: 'actionButton',
        img: '/language.svg',
        onClick: () => {
            const quads = docViewer.getSelectedTextQuads(docViewer.getCurrentPage());
            const text = docViewer.getSelectedText();
            $("#out-pdf").html(text);
            console.log(quads);
        },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Document does seem to cause incorrect extraction. Extraction is not defined by PDF specification so every viewer handles cases little differently. I your case there is a probably a malformed or incomplete font or unicode map included in the document. We've added multiple fixes to our core components and with those fixes extraction happens correctly. Unfortunately current release of WebViewer does not include these fixes yet. We cannot give exact time schedule when fixes will be land to the WebViewer, but should be at least part of our next major release. For now I would try to see if you can recreate the document and see if that helps. Most of the documents we see and test have no problem with extraction.

Answer (score 1):

Could you create ticket through our support https://www.pdftron.com/form/request/ and attach the document that this happens to the ticket, so I can take a closer look on and get issue resolved faster.

Comment: tnx for your attention, i created ticket.

Comment: i didn't receive any answer

Comment: @AbolfazlMohajeri we are unable to locate your ticket. You should have received an email from PDFTron confirming that we received your submission. That email would have a link to your ticket. You can safely post that ticket number here for us to locate. Otherwise, we could just continue resolving here in this question, by adding your file to your question above.

Comment: @Ryan tnx for your reply, yes i didn't receive any email form pdftron. I share my file here in my question.

Comment: Thanks @AbolfazlMohajeri. I'll take a closer look at the file.